# View Debugging: What are the layers of view in any View Controller?

Tags: ios, uiview, uistatusbar, uiview-hierarchy

For example, when I add a table view to my view controller what would the view hierarchy be? Is UIWindow always the base View of the hierarchy?
In which layer does the Status Bar lie?

I mostly write code programmatically, therefore, have some queries while **visualizing** the hierarchy.

Comment: Try Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xcode debugger provides the ability to inspect and understand the view hierarchy.

With your app running in the debugger, click the Debug View Hierarchy button in the debug bar.
[image]

Here is reference of visual code debugging.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

[image]